# How do I set a Many-to-Many relation for predefined chocies in Django models?

Tags: django

I have a `WorderOrder` class that has predefined work order types:

```
class WorkOrder( models.Model ) :
    WORK_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ( 'hc', 'Heating and cooling' ),
        ( 'el', 'Electrical'          ),
        ( 'pl', 'Plumbing'            ),
        ( 'ap', 'Appliances'          ),
        ( 'pe', 'Pests'               ),
        ( 'ex', 'Exterior'            ),
        ( 'in', 'Interior'            ),
        ( 'ot', 'Others'              ),
    )

    work_type = models.CharField( max_length = 2, choices = WORK_TYPE_CHOICES )
    vendor    = models.ForeignKey( Vendor, null = True, blank = True )
```

Therefore each order must have one work order type. Later down the road, a vendor can also be assigned to a work order.

I want the `Vendor` class to have a M2M relationship to the *same work order choices* in the `WorkOrder` class. In other words, each vendor are able to do one or many work types. For example, Bob's Plumbing can only do "Plumbing", whereas Solid Home Repair can do "Electrical", "Plumbing", "Exterior", and "Interior".

I understand I can create another table called `WorkType` and use foreign keys from `WorkOrder` and a M2M from `Vendor`, but since I feel I won't be changing the work type choices, I would rather have them predefined in `models.py`.

Also if I can predefine it in `models.py`, then I don't have to pre-populate the table `WorkType` during deployments and upgrades.

Comment: Does one WorkOrder engage one Vendor to do a number of WorkTypes? That would be one to many, not many to many, wouldn't it?

Comment: @John Mee Ummm not sure how to answer your question. Let me try to clarify: Each WorkOrder have one WorkType. Each Vendor have many WorkType. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options for you:

1. create a model for work_type_choices, instantiate the records (hc, el, etc), then use a manytomany field, or
2. create a charfield and save CSV values to it (eg: "hc, el"), spliting/joining the value into it's elements as required, or
3. encapsule the above charfield and functions into a custom field and use that
4. leverage someone else's snippet, eg:
   http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1200/

Comment: Hmm I like option #1. Should I instantiate the record in `models.py` and make sure it only runs once? What is your recommendation on where to instantiate the records?

Comment: Fixtures as documented, or I think I've also done this kind of thing with a list of saves in the apps __init__.py